# Can not run " npm start " in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

I have a problem when I run my ReactJS project. It shows for me like this
[image]

Although I already install `npm install i`, it also show me that error, can anyone help me with this, Please? Thank you so much.

Comment: Does the package.json file exist in that location? How did you create the project?

Comment: Yes, it does. I cloned my project from Gitlab, and then I installed npm install I to install node modules

Comment: `npm install i` installs a package called "i", it should be either `npm install` or `npm i` but not both at the same time. That shouldn't cause the error, though.

Comment: ...but now that you edited the question with a different error message, that one *is* caused by not running `npm install` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should run npm start from the directory where `package.json` is located. You might need to cd into that directory

Comment: can you provide the full path to your folder structure you have posted in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install i
```

Is giving error because there is no such package as `i` therefore if you are trying to install the packages in your package.json file use-
`npm i`
or
`npm install`